# Iterate over duplicate partitions/groups of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

I have a df like this

```
id val1 val2 val3
0   1   1     2
1   1   NaN   2
2   1   4     2
3   1   4     2
4   2   1     1
5   3   NaN   3
6   3   7     3
7   3   7     3
```

then

```
temp_df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['val1','val3'], keep=False)]
```

gives me this

```
id val1 val2 val3
0   1   1     2
1   1   NaN   2
2   1   4     2
3   1   4     2
5   3   NaN   3
6   3   7     3
7   3   7     3
```

How can I iterate over each partition/group containing the duplicate values?

```
for partition in temp_df......:
    print(partition)

id val1 val2 val3
0   1   1     2
1   1   NaN   2
2   1   4     2
3   1   4     2

id val1 val2 val3
5   3   NaN   3
6   3   7     3
7   3   7     3
```

The goal is to impute the NaN value with the mode of the partition columns. E.g `mode(1, 4, 4) = 4` so I want to fill in the NaN value of the first partition with 4. Similarly, I want to fill in the NaN value of the second partition with 7.

Comment: `df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['val1','val3'])]` outputs this for me (encoded, call `print` with the following): `"    val1  val2  val3\nid                  \n1      1   NaN   2.2\n5      3   1.5   6.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Use `groupby_apply`:

```
df['val2'] = df.groupby(['val1', 'val3'])['val2'] \
               .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode().squeeze()))
print(df)

# Output:
   id  val1  val2  val3
0   0     1   1.0     2
1   1     1   4.0     2
2   2     1   4.0     2
3   3     1   4.0     2
4   4     2   1.0     1
5   5     3   7.0     3
6   6     3   7.0     3
7   7     3   7.0     3
```

---

**Old answer**

IIUC, use `groupby` after sorting dataframe by `val2` then fill forward:

```
df['val2'] = df.sort_values('val2').groupby(['val1', 'val3'])['val2'].ffill()
print(df)

# Output:
   id  val1  val2  val3
0   0     1   1.1   2.2
1   1     1   1.1   2.2
2   3     2   1.3   1.0
3   4     3   1.5   6.2
4   5     3   1.5   6.2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, no because I have 10s of rows in each partition, so cannot use ffill. I can reformulate the question to make it more clear.